# What could cause a Windows 11 machine to have so much more elapsed time relative to a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: operating-systems, efficiency, memory-hardware, os-kernel, comparison

I have a Windows 10 desktop (6 years old - Dell Optiplex) and a new Windows 11 laptop (maybe last years model - Lenovo Thinkpad P16 Gen2).

I am running scripts in R to compare their compute times. The new machine is roughly twice as fast on average, but a significant portion of that time is occurring outside of user+system. I use the R function `system.time()` to time the scripts. It outputs 3 variables: user time, system time, elapsed time.

Here is a good explanation on what these different components of time measure and what can affect them, including a few programs that impinge on each variable in different ways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688840/what-caused-my-elapsed-time-much-longer-than-user-time

Whenever I have timed a script, I have always had the elapsed time be very close to the user+system time total. This is still true on my much older Windows 7 laptop even for the same script. **I would like to figure out why this new Thinkpad laptop is so different.**

Let me first argue that this is an acceptable question for this site. My thought is that it has to do with the hardware or operating system. This is a question about machine/hardware-specific input/output or memory management issues. This is not about the specific code I am using as I have tested several different R scripts. I have also ruled out that it is an R version issue. My gut intuition tells me it is something different between the operating systems, and specifically the kernel (after reading the linked post above).

Can somebody help me figure out what is so different about Windows 11 vs Windows 10 & 7 that could cause this? Or maybe it could be a hardware issue? I am open to other potential answers of course. I didn't test other programs, e.g. Matlab (since I only think it has  a method for total elapsed time and doesn't break it down into system & user time).

Here are what I thought were the important machine specs:

| Dell Optimplex desktop (2018 model) | Lenovo ThinkPad P16 Gen2 laptop (2023/4 model) |
| --- | --- |
| Intel Core i7-8700 (6 Cores/12MB/12T/base 3.20 GHz/up to 4.6GHz/65W) | 13th Generation Intel Core i7-13700HX Processor (16 Cores/30MB/24T/base 3.70 GHz/up to 5.0GHz/55W) |
| Windows 10 Pro 64bit | Windows 11 Pro 64 |
| 64GB 4X16GB 2666MHz DDR4 UDIM Non-ECC | 64 GB DDR5-4000MHz (SODIMM) - (2 x 32 GB) |
| M.2 512GB PCIe NVMe Class 40 Solid State Drive | 1 TB SSD M.2 2280 PCIe Gen4 Performance TLC Opal |
| NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, 4GB (DP/HDMI/DL-DVI) | NVIDIA RTX 3500 Ada Generation Laptop GPU 12GB GDDR6 |